# Stellar Classification Table and Star RNG

Tags: star, mathematics, resource-request

I found a [table](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/astro/HR-temp-mass-table-byhrclass.html) that was based on data from 2003 for Stellar Classification, and I can't get to the given data source. I plan on using the table as a basis for a program that spits out random star systems with stars +-5% of the given data.

I know type R was renamed to C so I am already throwing that out. Is there anything else I should ignore from this table or add?

Or this table is crap and should not be used as there are glaring errors.

Comment: The table looks pretty good to me, it's a wealth of useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found a table that was based on data from 2003 for Stellar Classification, and I can't get to the given data source ...

The website that was the source of the data was last active  in 2006. I've replaced the broken URLs with working URLs. I wouldn't recommend relying on data that old, there's likely a newer source.

**Original (404) Text and URLs**:

> Credit:
>
> The table data was obtained from [SpaceGear.Org](http://www.spacegear.org/)'s [SCTable](http://www.spacegear.org/data/SCTable/sctable.3.0.csv) version 3.0 09/23/2003. The following data source was obtained from their [SCTable web page](http://www.spacegear.org/data/SCTable/):

**Original Text and repaired URLs:**

> Credit:
>
> The table data was obtained from [SpaceGear.Org](https://web.archive.org/web/20060410153507/http://www.spacegear.org/)'s [SCTable](https://web.archive.org/web/20061012065012/http://www.spacegear.org/data/SCTable/sctable.3.0.csv) version 3.0 09/23/2003. The following data source was obtained from their [SCTable web page](https://web.archive.org/web/20061012065004/http://www.spacegear.org/data/SCTable/):

---

The 3rd links says that they derived the data from:

> Absolute magnitude was derived from the standard Hertzsprung-Russell (HR) diagram. The book [Stars and Their Spectra by James B. Kaler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521899540) was used as a resource for deriving the absolute magnitude for each possible luminosity class. Classifications N, S, WC, WN, C, and R are mapped as follows:

```
N and S are equivalent to M.
WC and WN are equivalent to O.
C spans G4 to M9.
R spans G4 to M0.
```

> Temperature was derived from the relationship between luminosity class and spectral class. The book [Stars and Their Spectra by James B. Kaler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521899540) and [Mitchell Charity's work on star colors](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/starcolor/) was used as a resource for deriving temperature for Main Sequence (V), Supergiant (Ia), Giant (II), and Dwarf (D) luminosity classes. Luminosity classes Ia0, Ib, III, IV, and VI are mapped as follows:

```
Temperatures of Ia0 and Ib are equivalent to Ia.
Temperatures of II is equivalent to III.
Temperatures of IV and VI are equivalent to V.
```

> Color was derived from [Mitchell Charity's work on star colors](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/starcolor/). Each designated color is defined with at least one field (R, G, or B) at full saturation (value equals 255). Actual color values for display would be attenuated across all color components based on the star's apparent magnitude in a given situation.
>
> Mass was derived from many sources including [Astrophysical Formulae by Kenneth R. Lang](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783662216415). Many rows are heavily interpolated from known data on star mass.

---

See how I fixed all the URLs so they work correctly. If there is more from that webpage that you wanted sources for then you can use the same method. Since I was able to get to the raw CSV data that should be easier to use in your program.

See also Wikipedia's webpage on [Stellar Classification](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification).

An example of a website providing similar data (from 2015) is: "[The Mag 5 Star Catalog](http://www.johnpratt.com/items/astronomy/mag_5_stars.html)" or see: "[The HYG Database](http://www.astronexus.com/hyg)", his latest update to [GitHub](https://github.com/astronexus/HYG-Database) is a couple of years ago.